# Maven multimodule project,pick dependencies from local repo only and not touch remote repo

Tags: maven, installation, dependencies

I have a multimodule maven project . Module A got all 3rd party dependencies in its pom, module B has dependency A and 3rd party dependencies. Similarly, Module C has dependency of B and 3rd party dependencies.
Problem- Now when I do mvn install, my requirement is that module A should be installed in local .newm2 repo(local maven repo different from .m2), and for module B(when it compiles), it should pick dependency of A from local .newm2 repo only. How can I achieve this? It’s picking up from remote repo.
All the dependencies of child modules should be picked up from local m2 repo only. 3rd party can be picked from nexus.can someone help how to achieve this?

Comment: If you have a nexus repository manager you can control where dependencies will be picked from simply by defining rules in nexus repository manager.

Comment: @khmarbaise can we do it without touching nexus? Only using local?

Comment: What's the problem? And answer to local no it's no possible to handle that. Only repository manager can handle that .... local is only a cache which has not such options ... I strong recommend to handle that via repository manager via groupId/artifactId/..